# How should I use Draper in my ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, hierarchy

My questions refers to the following development stack:

- Rails 3.2.1
- Draper 0.14
- Ancestry 1.2.5

What I want to do is, deliver the navigation to my layout. So I've defined a before filter in my `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  [..]
  before_filter :current_navigation
  [..]
  def current_navigation
    @n = PublicationDecorator.find(1)
  end
end
```

As you see in the code listing above, I'm using the `draper`. My `PublicationDecorator` isn't available in the `ApplicationController`. **So** how do I get all my `Publications` decorated?

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PublicationDecorator
```

I'm using the `ancestry` gem to realize a hierarchy. A **further question** is, will be all objects decorated, if I'm using `ancestry`?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884740/nested-attributes-with-draper-and-rails-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `PublicationDecorator` available in your `ApplicationController`.

```
require 'publication_decorator.rb' # <--
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  [..]
  before_filter :current_navigation
  [..]
  def current_navigation
    @n = PublicationDecorator.find(1)
  end
end
```

To get children or even parents decorated add the association to your decorator:

```
class PublicationDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :publication
  decorates_association :children
  [..]

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question is more about, whether I've understood to use the given technology in this situation. Please heed my 'between' and 'further' question.

Comment: Added some information to your answer that it complettly answer my question.