# How to decorate nested attributes (associations) with Draper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, draper

My environment:

- Rails 3.2

  - with [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) gem

I'm using nested resources and having trouble figuring out where to declare the decorator.

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = UserDecorator.find(params[:id])
  @items = @user.items
end

#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
def show
  @item = @user.items.find(params[:id])
end
```

I tried replacing `items` with `ItemDecorator` and it didn't work. Where should I be putting it?

I know that Draper has issues with nested resources in forms, but this isn't a form!

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870306/how-should-i-use-draper-in-my-applicationcontroller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I've understood your problem correctly, you've a model `user` which has many `items`, but your `items` were not decorated?

So add to your `UserDecorator`:

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :user
  decorates_association :items #, :with => :item 

  [..]
end

class ItemDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :item

  [..]
end
```

Have a look on [the source](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper/blob/master/lib/draper/base.rb).