# Decorate relation object in a parent objects view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I'm using Draper to decorate my objects.

I have a model 'starts' that has_one horse.  I have a horse decorator that has a boy_or_girl method that I have refactored form the horse mode.

```
#{start.horse.boy_or_girl}"
```

I'm getting a method not found on the boy_or_girl method. How do i decorate the related horse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just call draper in your partial `#{start.horse.decorate.boy_or_girl}"`?

If you want to call the decorator only in the controller, you should use [decorates_association](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#adding-context)

I guess you will have something like

```
class StartDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :start
  decorates_association :horses
  ...
end

class HorseDecorator < Draper::Base
  decorates :horse

  def boy_or_girl
    # your code
  end
  ...
end
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884740/how-to-decorate-nested-attributes-associations-with-draper-in-rails-3)

Comment: ug.  im an idiot.  didn't restart rails after adding draper.  yes, start.horse.decorate.boy_or_girl works.  thanks.